# laravel 8 does not set homepage like in 7x version

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-8

I would like to set the home page of laravel 8 as that of laravel 7x.
to do this I wrote the following route:

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome', [PollController::class, 'element']);
```

I just keep seeing the following page:[image]

Comment: if I put Route::get('/','welcome', [PollController::class, 'element']); gives me Invalid route action: [welcome] but the file is in views / welcome.blade.php

Comment: because I would like to pass in the root / a view inside which there is a value obtained with the controller

Comment: in the Laravel 7x version it was enough for me to do so Route::get('/', 'PollController@element');

Comment: if I put it this way Route::get('/', [PollController::class, 'element']); it gives me an error and I don't have the view like in the 7x version

Comment: maybe i didn't explain myself badly the problem is in laravel 8 the default page is laravel/framework/src/illuminate/Foundation/views/minimal.blade.php while in laravel 7x it is views/welcome.blade.php in fact I would like to put that as the default page

Comment: Because by default Laravel 8 shows me the other, but I would like to set the old welcome

Comment: Route::get('/', [PollController::class, 'element'], function () {
    return view('welcome');
});    in this way it doesn't take me the views resources/views/welcome.blade.php but vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/views and I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('/', [PollController::class, 'element'], function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I renamed the file `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` in `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` and it worked

Comment: `Route::get` only takes **2** arguments, not 3 ...  `public function get($uri, $action = null)`